# How to insert a page break without DocumentBuilder?

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words

I have a template document containing header/footer into it I have to insert multiple documents. After each document I need to insert a page break.

There is an `insertDocument()` and an `insertBreak()` in the `com.aspose.words.DocumentBuilder`.

I would prefer to use the `com.aspose.words.NodeImporter` because it is more flexible. This works fine but I don't find a way to insert a page break afterwards.

Are there any other methods to insert content (e.g. paragraphs, breaks) than using the `DocumentBuilder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following approach:

```
doc.FirstSection.Body.FirstParagraph.Runs.Add(new Run(doc, ControlChar.PageBreak));
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: So I'm using this code:
`doc.getLastSection().getBody().getLastParagraph().getRuns().add(new Run(doc, ControlChar.PAGE_BREAK));`, but what if the last element of the document is not a `Paragraph` but a `Table`, how do I insert the page brake after the `Table`?

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the following code:

```
Document doc = new Document(filePath);
NodeCollection col = doc.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Paragraph, true);
Paragraph para = (Paragraph)col[col.Count - 2];
Table tab = (Table)para.GetAncestor(NodeType.Table);
if (tab != null)
{
    // it means last para is inside table
    Paragraph newPara = new Paragraph(doc);
    newPara.Runs.Add(new Run(doc, ControlChar.PageBreak));
    newPara.ParagraphBreakFont.Size = 1;
    tab.ParentNode.InsertAfter(newPara, tab);
}else
{
    // normal case
}
doc.Save(MyDir + @"16.7.0.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.